# Best practice when producing a C++ static or dynamic library for others?

Tags: c++, conventions

I'm providing a Microsoft C++ library (static and dynamic) for other clients in my company. My library has a few classes that depend upon functions located in common Windows DLLs whose import libraries *aren't* included in the project link settings by default.

Rather than add a new import library name to the linker section of every build configuration of my library each time a new dependency like this came up, I thought it would be better in terms of encapsulation of dependencies (and a bit more self-documenting) if I used `#pragma comment(lib, ...)` in the .cpp file of the class that depended upon a function from such a DLL, e.g.:

**Foo.cpp:**

```
#include <SomeWinLib.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "somewinlib.lib")

... implementation of Foo class ...
```

...but I found that this was causing link warnings/errors for clients of my library if they were also using SomeWinLib. After doing some reading on the subject, it seems that the recommended/best practice is to let the client who is linking in my library also link in the libraries it depends upon.

I still wanted this to be as automatic/painless as possible for the clients, so rather than just put a list of required import libraries in a readme.txt file (and then sit back and wait for the inevitable phone calls from frustrated developers), I'd just place the `#pragma comment` in the Foo.h *header file*. That way, clients would automatically link in the required library if they included the header file of a class that required it.

**Foo.h:**

```
#pragma comment(lib, "somewinlib.lib")

public class Foo
{
```

However, when I build my library, Foo.cpp includes Foo.h obviously, so it would seem that I need some kind of preprocessor "guard" around the `#pragma comment` line in the header file so that it's only seen by the preprocessor when clients include my header file.

**Foo.h:**

```
#if !defined(building_my_library)
  #pragma comment(lib, "somewinlib.lib")
#endif

public class Foo
{
```

All of this seems like something that pretty much EVERY library must be doing, yet I don't see examples of this when I Google other open source Windows libraries. That makes me suspect I've missed something somewhere.

Does anyone know if I'm understanding the issues correctly, and if so, whether I'm over-complicating the solution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last option is more or less what the boost headers do, except they also provide a preprocessor directive to explicitly turn off the auto-linking in case you want to control things yourself:

```
#if !defined(building_my_library) && !defined(no_auto_link_stuff)
    #pragma comment(lib, "somelib.lib")
#endif
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks Miles. Funny thing is that I'm using boost, and I never saw this. Of course, looking through boost (or other template-heavy) header files generally makes my eyes glaze over pretty quickly.

Answer (score 1):

A solution that you might not have considered is to use runtime linkage to the DLL via `LoadLibrary` and `GetProcAddress`, removing the dependence on **somewinlib.lib**.

Comment: True, late binding would be a way to avoid this issue altogether, but I usually only go that route if there's a possibility that the DLL won't be present at runtime. Besides being more work (and not so much *solving* the problem as *avoiding* it), doing this would also introduce a new error condition (DLL not found) that would require even more code to detect and do something about.

Comment: Not to put too fine a point on it, but for the benefit of anyone reading this at some point in the future, besides trading a link-time error for a run-time error, dynamically loading *required* DLLs (i.e., DLLs that must be present) has the disadvantage of hiding these dependencies from tools like Depends.exe, DumpBin.exe, etc.